# Create a MSBuild file in vs 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, build, msbuild

I have a web application build on .net 3.5 that is built using VS 2010 pro edition. I am trying to automate the build task for msbuild. Is there a way to make a build file of my project in VS 2010? Or do I have to make the build file from scratch?

Comment: VS already creates an MSBuild file. It's in your project's folder, and has a `.cproj` extension. This file can be passed directly to MSBuild (provided that the correct `PATH` and environmental variables are set).

Comment: I can't seem to find the .csproj file right now. I have it for my projects but this is a build -> Web Site, is there a .csproj for that too?

Comment: There is no msbuild file for website project. You should use web project to have msbuild file.

Answer (score 1):

There's a tool that can help you creating your own msbuild file and it also has GUI, MS Build Sidekick:
http://www.attrice.info/msbuild/

MS Build Sidekick isn't free but it's quite cheap (US$55), and they also offer trial version for 14 days.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do it from scratch... file->new->text file...

pretty good tutorial on msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd576348.aspx

Comment: yeah i was reading that one, seems like there should be a tool or something in vs tho

Comment: it is actually pretty easy... and this is the best resource on debugging: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/07/06/debugging-msbuild-script-with-visual-studio.aspx